# Optimized code to check the element of list unique or not

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x

python3 program that takes input a list and output if it is unique or not. The following is an example:

```
list_a = [1,2,3,4,5] #unique
list_b = [1,2,2,3,4] #not unique
```

I have wrote a python3 script for this problem:

```
for i in range(len(list_a)):
   j = i+1
   for j in range(len(list_a)):
      if list_a[i] == list_a[j]:
         print ("not unique")
      else:
         print ("unique")
```

Is this the only way to check it. I bet it isn't! I want some optimized code that is equivalent to above or simply that ouputs "unique" or "not unique" for a given list.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both your examples are sorted. Are your inputs sorted? I think this would change the algorithm considerably.

Comment: Oh no it is not. Not sorted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is compare length of set of given list with length of list:

```
if len(l) != len(set(l)):
    # not unique
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `all()` and sets, this will short-circuit as soon as a repeated item is found.

```
>>> def solve(lis):
...     seen = set()
...     return all(item not in seen and not seen.add(item) for item in lis)
... 
>>> solve(range(5))
True
>>> solve([1,2,2,3,4])
False
```

Comment: This appears to be the most efficient algorithm presented.

Comment: I wonder at what point the overhead of this starts to cost more than it saves.....

Comment: This is a lot slower than just creating a set of everything. For a list of 100 items (no duplicates, or duplicate at the end of the list) this already took 5 times as long. For a list with a duplicate at the beginning, this is indeed about twice as fast, but when the duplicate is at the middle, this is already 2.5 times slower. The changing point seems to be around index 15 (out of 100) where this solutions gets slower than a simple length check. So I’d say: Not worth it. Is better in best case, but a lot worse in average and worse case, while the length check has a *constant* time.

Comment: (Note that adding list items individually to a set is always significantly slower than creating a set from the list directly, so that’s where a lot of the penalty comes from.)

Answer (score 6):

Throw the list into a set:

```
set_a = set(list_a)
if len(set_a) == len(list_a):
    print("unique")
else:
    print("not unique")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use AVL Trees, add each element one by one in the tree while the inserted element is not yet in the tree.

In the case of big lists, it will be very fast in comparison of your current code.

Comment: Implementing any kind of mapping data structure yourself is overkill.

Comment: I don't say he has to implement it himself: he can use https://github.com/pgrafov/python-avl-tree/ (for example). The method 'find' is defined.

Comment: If the check for “unique” or “not unique” is all you want to do, an AVL tree is quite exaggerated. A simple hash table with a constant insertion and lookup is way more efficient than anything else.

Comment: Pulling in a third party library is also overkill when the builtins work at least as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily find duplicate elements you can use collections.Counter:

```
import collections
a = [1, 2, 2, 3]
b = collections.Counter(a)
duplicates = [i for i in b if b[i] > 1]
```

Variable `b` is an object which acts a bit like a dictionary with keys being values from `a` and values being numbers indicating how many times this value appeared in the original list.

```
print(b[2])
```

would give 2.

Variable `duplicates` has all duplicate elements and you can use it like this:

```
if duplicates:
    print("not unique")
else:
    print("unique")
```

This is longer than generating a set, but you have much more information you can use.